# Read functions as text and use for plotting

Tags: r, function, plot, text

I have a set of 500 equations listed in a single column of a .csv file. The equations are written as text like this (for example):

> `15+6.2*A-4.3*B+3.7*C-7.9*B*C+2*D^2`

(this is the "right" side of the equation, which equals "y", but the text "y=" does not appear in the .csv file)

These are general linear models that have been written to a .csv file by someone else. Not all models have the same number of variables.

I would like to read these functions into R and format them in a way that will allow for using them to (iteratively) make simple line plots (one for each n = 500 models) of "y" across a range of values for A (shown on the x-axis), given values of B, C, and D.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: Every equation has an intercept and this relationship between A, B, C and D?

Comment: Every equation does have an intercept, but different relationships between A, B, C and D (and sometimes additional variables too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of something based on this [post][1], it is not the best solution, but it seems to work.

### Equations

Created two equations for an example

```
models <- c("15+6.2*A-4.3*B+3.7*C-7.9*B*C+2*D^2","50+6.2*A-4.3*B+3.7*C-7.9*B*C+2*D^2")
models_names <- c("model1","model2")
```

### Data

Random data as an example

```
data <-
tibble(
  A = rnorm(100),
  B = rnorm(100),
  C = rnorm(100),
  D = rnorm(100)
)
```

### Function

Then a created a function that uses those text equations and apply as function returning the values

```
text_model <- function(formula){
  eval(parse(text = paste('f <- function(A,B,C,D) { return(' , formula , ')}', sep='')))
  out <- f(data$A,data$B,data$C,data$D)
  return(out)
}
```

### Applied equations

Finally, I apply each equation for the data, binding both.

```
data %>% 
  bind_cols(
    map(.x = models,.f = text_model) %>% 
      set_names(models_names) %>% 
      bind_rows(.id = "model") 
  )

# A tibble: 100 x 6
          A       B      C       D model1 model2
      <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -0.0633   1.18   -0.409  2.01     9.52   54.9
 2 -0.00207  1.35    1.28   1.59     9.16   40.3
 3  0.798   -0.141   1.58  -0.123   20.6    63.2
 4 -0.162   -0.0795  0.408  0.663   14.3    52.0
 5 -1.11     0.788  -1.37   1.20     4.71   46.0
 6  2.80     1.84   -0.850  0.161   24.4    68.7
 7  1.03     0.550   0.907 -1.92    19.0    60.8
 8  0.515   -0.179  -0.980  0.0437  19.0    48.9
 9 -0.353    0.0643  1.39   1.30    12.5    55.3
10 -0.427   -1.01   -1.11  -0.547   16.7    39.3
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: How does this address having only two variables (A and C, for example) or more than four variables (A, B, C, D, E and F, for example)?

Comment: No problem if the equation has less variables, but if they have more variables it will give an error since in `text_model` I defined A, B, C and D

Comment: Ok, I will add the full set of variables to 'text_model' and try this...

Comment: This seems to work well. There is another field in the .csv file with names for each model (model001, model002...etc). Any suggestions for how to use these names (rather than the full equation) in the output table header row?

Comment: I marked this as the the accepted answer to the original question, but it would still help to know if/how a different column (from the input .csv file with the equations) can be used for naming the header row in the output table

Comment: @viridius a simple solution is to pass another vector with the names of the models. I created a model called `models_names`